# CLOB and int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway

Tags: spring-integration, clob

I'm trying to invoke a stored procedure using the following component:

```
int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway
```

It works fine, it calls the procedure but I can't seem to be able to log the CLOB in a proper CLOB format.
I've tried the following xml:

```
<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway
        id="auditGatewayProcedure" request-channel="auditGatewayInbound"
        data-source="dataSource" stored-procedure-name="PKG_TEMP.PR_AUDIT"
        return-value-required="false" ignore-column-meta-data="true">
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition
            name="IN_MSG_ID" />
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition
            name="IN_GUID" />
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition
            name="IN_CLOB" />
        <int-jdbc:parameter name="IN_MSG_ID" expression="payload.msgId" />
        <int-jdbc:parameter name="IN_CLOB" expression="payload.xmlPayload" />
        <int-jdbc:parameter name="IN_GUID" expression="payload.guid" />
</int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>
```

With that in mind, I'm passing the following payload (with the proper getters and setters):

```
private long id;
private String msgId;
private Clob xmlPayload;
private String guid;
```

The CLOB is of type: `java.sql.Clob`

The procedure I'm calling is this simple stuff:

```
procedure PR_BRIDGE_AUDIT(in_msg_id IN varchar2,
                                 in_guid IN varchar2,
                                 in_clob IN Clob) is begin
    insert into tb_temp_all_messages(id,msg_id,xml_payload,guid) values (TB_TEMP_ALL_MESSAGES_SEQ.NEXTVAL,in_msg_id, in_clob, in_guid);

end;
```

What happens is that the clob column is inserted with the following value:

```
org.hibernate.lob.SerializableClob@186fdd6
```

The second try I did was forcing the type in the spring component, like this:

```
<int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition
            name="IN_CLOB" type="CLOB"/>
```

But the following exception is thrown: `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.lob.SerializableClob cannot be cast to oracle.sql.CLOB`

Am I doing something wrong?

I tried to google it but nothing of value (as far as I saw) appeared.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

So, after some tries and the answer from Artem, the solutions are two, it seems:

given this XML:

```
<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway
        id="auditGatewayProcedure" request-channel="auditGatewayInbound"
        data-source="dataSource" stored-procedure-name="PKG_TGT_BRIDGE.PR_BRIDGE_AUDIT"
        return-value-required="false" ignore-column-meta-data="true">
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition
            name="IN_MSG_ID" />
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition
            name="IN_GUID" />
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition
            name="IN_CLOB" type="CLOB"/>
        <int-jdbc:parameter name="IN_MSG_ID" expression="payload.msgId" />
        <int-jdbc:parameter name="IN_CLOB" expression="payload.stringClob" />
        <int-jdbc:parameter name="IN_GUID" expression="payload.guid" />
</int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>
```

In the EEM class you can either pass a string containing the Clob (stringClob).
Or create a properly oracle.sql.CLOB type with what has been said by Artem and pass into the IN_CLOB parameter the oracle.sql.CLOB created.

Hope this helped,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you really must create `oracle.sql.CLOB` yourself and within the same transaction as for that `<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>`.

The code to create a `CLOB` may look like:

```
public CLOB convertToClob(String value) {
    CLOB c = CLOB.createTemporary(getNativeConnection(), false, CLOB.DURATION_SESSION);
    c.setString(1L, value);
    return c;
}

private Connection getNativeConnection() {
    return DataSourceUtils.getConnection(this.dataSource).getMetaData().getConnection();
}
```

Comment: I'm trying this right now.
@ArtemBilan In the meantime I noticed that if I pass a String in the supposedly CLOB parameter it correctly chomps it and happyly put it in the DB...

I guess I could skip the part where I generate a temporary CLOB and pass directly the String value?

Comment: m-m-m. Try to put to that param some really big string, more than `4000` symbols

Comment: It works fine in both cases (I've tried with a String and Clob of length > 4500

Thanks for the help!